# Adafruit_BMP no python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

Estou a testar o sensor BMP180 no RaspberryPi 3 B+ e quando mando correr o ficheiro no Raspbian dá-me este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando executo o mesmo ficheiro pela linha de comandos ele dá os valores que deve dar, não dá erro, como se pode ver pela imagem seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o que pode estar a acontecer para dar este erro?

Comment: Amigo, aconselho fazer essa pergunta em outra [comunidade](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) voltada para raspberry-pi. Aqui é voltado para programação.

Comment: Na primeira imagem está executando no Python3+ e na segunda no Python2+, veja se o módulo está instalado no Python3+ também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os módulos não são compartilhados entre as versões do Python.

Por padrão, na Raspbian o comando `python` aponta para a versão 2.7 do Python. Você pode confirmar isso através da segunda linha da imagem do seu terminal

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Nov 24 2017, 17:33:09)
```

Já, ao executar pelo IDLE, você está a rodar com a versão 3.5.3, vide primeira linha que aparece no programa

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04)
```

Ou seja, você possui o módulo `Adafruit_BMP` instalado corretamente na versão 2.7, mas não na 3.5. Basta você ver qual irá utilizar. Se for a 2.7, precisará abrir o IDLE nesta versão também, mas caso for a 3.5, terá que instalar o módulo nesta versão.

Comment: ok, e onde posso arranjar essa biblioteca para a versão 3.5?

Comment: Provavelmente no repositório oficial.